# Why is subsetting in sf removing some geometry?

Tags: geometry, r-sf, ogr

I'm cleaning an sf file using package sf. When I write out the file using write_sf, all of the geometry is there. But when I read it back in using readOGR, it reports: "Dropping null geometries" and drops 430 lines. I need to read it back in with OGR because I'm then binding it to another object. The way I'm subsetting is kind of wonky - is that what's causing it to drop geometries? Any help is appreciated!

```
'fsvtrt <- read_sf("C:/Users/A02305035/Desktop/JamelaResearch/Data/GIS/FS/fsvtrt.shp") #raster package'
```

#### Add ObjectID

```
fsvtrt$OBJECTID <- seq(1:5464)
```

#### Remove incomplete treatments

```
fsunwanted1 <- fsvtrt$DATE_COMPL[is.na(fsvtrt$DATE_COMPL)]
incomplete <- fsvtrt[fsvtrt$DATE_COMPL %in% fsunwanted1,]

salvagetx <- incomplete[na.omit(incomplete$STAGE_VALU),]

unique(incomplete$STAGE_VALU)
```

#### Find and remove planned future treatments

```
planned <- fsvtrt$DATE_PLANN[fsvtrt$DATE_PLANN>as.Date("2020-02-13")]
```

#### Identify planned future treatments

```
fsvtrt <- fsvtrt[!fsvtrt$DATE_PLANN %in% planned,]
```

#### Show treatments that have occurred, excluding planned ones

#### Remove incomplete treatments

```
incomplete <- fsvtrt$DATE_COMPL[is.na(fsvtrt$DATE_COMPL)]
fsvtrt <- fsvtrt[!fsvtrt$DATE_COMPL %in% incomplete,]
```

#### Remove wildfires

```
wildfires <- fsvtrt$ACTIVITY[fsvtrt$ACTIVITY == "Wildfire - Natural Ignition"]
fsvtrt <- fsvtrt[!fsvtrt$ACTIVITY %in% wildfires,]

wildfires1 <- fsvtrt$ACTIVITY[fsvtrt$ACTIVITY == "Wildland Fire Use"]
fsvtrt<-fsvtrt[!fsvtrt$ACTIVITY %in% wildfires1,]

wildfires2 <- "Wildfire - Fuels Benefit"
fsvtrt <- fsvtrt[!fsvtrt$ACTIVITY %in% wildfires2, ]

wildfires3 <- "Wildfire - Human Ignition"
fsvtrt <- fsvtrt[!fsvtrt$ACTIVITY %in% wildfires3, ]
```

Comment: Could you bind the other object in `sf` using `rbind`? https://r-spatial.github.io/sf/reference/bind.html

Comment: you can try either reading it with sf::st_read(), or if you want to stick with readOGR you can try setting the dropNULLGeometries argument to FALSE (BTW: looking at your code, you may have NULL geometries already in the input. Did you check that?)